# Set value in ArrayList<Object[]>

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

It's been a while since my data structures class and I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.  I know that if I want to get the value from an `ArrayList` of `Object[]` I can use

```
nameOfArrayList.get(row)[col];
```

but I can't seem to figure out, or find on the web, how to set a value.

Would I have to create a new object and set it to `nameOfArrayList.get(row)`, alter the value and then use

```
nameOfArrayList.set(row,Object[])?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
nameOfArray.get(row)[col] = ...;
```

This sets a new value at index `col` of the array at index `row` in the `nameOfArray` [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

If you want to put a new array into `nameOfArray` at position `row`, try this:

```
nameOfArray.set(row, new Object[]);
```

This creates a new array of objects and puts it under index `row` in `nameOfArray`. See [`ArrayList.set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

Comment: Wow, that is odd to me.  I wouldn't think an accessor method would actually be a mutator.  I can't believe it was that simple.  I see how it makes sense now, in essence it's getting the Object array through the nameOfArray.get() and the brackets with an int contained is the same as using the Object[int]= command. Thanks!

Comment: @Geoff - `get` is merely returning the array, a read-only operation. What you do with the array after that is your business. :) The above is equivalent to `Object[] arr = nameOfArray.get(row); arr[col] = ...;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple basic run.

If you want to add the Object at the end you can just use something like

`nameOfArray.add(<object array>)`

Else if you want it at a specified index something like above

`nameOfArray.set(index, <object array>)`

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

`<object array>.get(row)[col] = change value`

Comment: That's setting an entire row. I think the OP wants to set a particular row,column.

Comment: The first line to append should be `nameOfArray.add(<object array>)` instead of `set`. The latter always requires an index.